# Can't connect to minecraft servers after 1.7.2 update

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Both server and client are 1.7.2, that's for sure. I can connect to the same server with 1.7.2 client from another PC. But on my main PC I get this in console (using linux, oracle jdk 6, no luck with jdk 7):

```
[14:50:30 INFO]: Client> [14:50:30] [Client thread/INFO]: Connecting to ***.org, 25565
[14:50:30 INFO]: Client> Exception in thread "Server Connector #1" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[14:50:30 INFO]: Client>        at bbf.run(SourceFile:55)
[14:50:30 INFO]: Client> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
[14:50:30 INFO]: Client>        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:61)
[14:50:30 INFO]: Client>        at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:49)
[14:50:30 INFO]: Client>        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:61)
[14:50:30 INFO]: Client>        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:52)
[14:50:30 INFO]: Client>        at ef.<clinit>(SourceFile:41)
[14:50:30 INFO]: Client>        ... 1 more
```

Comment: is java updated on your pc that your having problems with?

Comment: Looks to me like you need to update java, or you have a conflicting mod. Is this ONLY when you connect to YOUR server or to all servers? Is your profile set to work with a base 1.7.2 or did you create a modded version of 1.7.2?

Answer (score 1):

It's always best to keep your Java version as updated as possible, because it's likely the server you are trying to reach is running Java version 7. Between Java versions, the actual code for Java changes, and the newer Minecraft versions were programmed to implement those changes. Part of your error message references Threads, which was one of the notable changes between Java 6 and 7.